# What are some websites for public transit directions in Buenos Aires, Argentina?

Tags: online-resources, public-transport, maps, argentina, buenos-aires

I generally use Google Maps, but they don't have transit directions for Buenos Aires. What are some similar sites that I can use, extra bonus for sites with mobile web interfaces and/or iPhone applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out:

- [ComoViajo.com](http://beta.comoviajo.com/)
- The official site for the [Buenos Aires
  Government Transportation Authority](http://mapa.buenosaires.gob.ar/) which has an [iPhone App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ba-como-llego/id576489186?mt=8)
- You might also consider the [Official City of Buenos Aires Website](http://www.buenosaires.gob.ar/)
- If you want to buy bus tickets to other cities, consider [Plataforma 10](http://www.plataforma10.com/)

If you are staying in Buenos Aires for a considerable time you will save money with the [SUBE](http://www.sube.gob.ar/) card. I am not sure about the requirements for foreigners though.